# Graph/Charts Solution

Tags: php, user-interface, graph

What is the best **Graph/Charts** Solution for

**PHP** that is **Interactive** (at least anchor points).

PS. I can't use flash, and it shouldn't relay on internet :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If flash is not possible you can try JS charts like

[HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/)  Offer a free licence for non-commercial use, based on jQuery
[GRaphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/) MIT Licence , based on the famous raphael library
[Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) With less interaction but still free
[JSCharts](http://www.jscharts.com/) A non-free alternative

Full PHP graph like jpgraph can't be interactive.

Answer (score 1):

The **[Google Chart Tools / Interactive Charts (aka Visualization API)](https://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/visualization/interactive_charts.html)** might be helpful, in your case ?

It provides flash-based interactive graphs *(that you can't use*), but it also provides **Javascript-based interactive graphs** *(that could be OK for you, I suppose ?)*

Here is an example / demo of a non flash-based chart : [**Visualization: Line Chart**](https://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/linechart.html).

Quoting that page, it :

> is rendered within the browser using
>   SVG or VML

Take a look at the [**Google Visualization API Gallery**](https://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery.html) to see what can be done ; maybe you'll find out it's OK for you ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but the project that i am going to user the charts in needs to run without Internet (Locally, Ethernet), so i can't user the Google API.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with highcharts.  I would also add [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/).